# Instalar SQL Server Data Tools en Visual Studio 2019

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis

Buen día, espero me puedan ayudar, tengo instalado el Visual Studio Community 2019, y quiero tener también el SQL Server Data Tools ya que necesito hacer unos packages para agilizar mi proceso en el software, pero no encuentro el sistema instalado para poder hacer los packages, anexo captura de la configuración de Visual Studio Installer.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes encontrar mas detallado en la documentación:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]